# Moving images from a dynamic list PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, list, picturebox

I am initiating me into programming thanks to Stack Overflow.
The game I'm doing in c #, consists of several bees flying around the desktop, which I have to give Click and SCORE is going to increase by a certain time.
To which I did the following:

- Create a list PictureBox dynamically (at runtime): OK
- Load PictureBox with these GIF images randomly: OK

![Bee Games][1]

In this part I was stuck:

- Place these randomly PictureBox (in the bottom of the form).
- Make the PictureBox move randomly (more or less marked routes).
- each PictureBox Click Event, Change the PictureBox image and hide (visible = false), and increase in SCORE + 1.

I need help please.
My code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace MiPrimerJuego
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = 20;
            int y = 600;
            List<System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox> objeto = new List<PictureBox>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++, x += 90)
            {
                PictureBox pBox = new PictureBox();                
                pBox.Height = 80;
                pBox.Width = 50;
                pBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
                objeto.Add(pBox);
                pBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;                
                Controls.Add(pBox);

                var rand = new Random();
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + @"/Images", "*.gif");
                pBox.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(files[rand.Next(files.Length)]);
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how to say this exactly, but if you've been told that StackOverflow is a place where you can be taught programming, then you've been misinformed. This site is for helping programers who are having specific problems with a specific bit of code, not for providing suggestions about how to program or how to design programs. I suggest you find some Internet tutorials on C# programming for games. Come back here when you have specific problems with some specific bit of code.

Comment: That said, I'm pretty sure you're going to need a Timer, and you'll need to set up the Timer to call a Tick event handler, and most of your code will probably be in the Tick event handler. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Declare rand and files outside the for-loop and objeto outside the function/void as a Private member variable:

```
    private List<PictureBox> objeto = new List<PictureBox>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + @"/Images", "*.gif");                          
        int x = 20;
        int y = 600;
        var rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
         {
            x += 90;
            PictureBox pBox = new PictureBox();                
            pBox.Height = 80;
            pBox.Width = 50;
            pBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
            objeto.Add(pBox);
            pBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;                
            Controls.Add(pBox);

            pBox.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(files[rand.Next(files.Length)]);
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I did not explain properly.

What I do is this:

1 Make the PictureBox move randomly from the bottom of the form (more or less marked routes).

2 In the Click event of each PictureBox, Changing the PictureBox image and hide (visible = false), and increase in SCORE + 1.

My code is as follows:

```
using System;
usingSystem.Collections.Generic;
usingSystem.ComponentModel;
usingSystem.Data;
usingSystem.Drawing;
usingSystem.Linq;
usingSystem.Text;
usingSystem.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespaceMiPrimerJuego
{
publicpartialclassForm1 : Form
    {        
public Form1()
        {
InitializeComponent();
        }

privatevoid button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int x = 20;
int y = 600;
List<System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox>objeto = newList<PictureBox>();
for (inti = 0; i< 10; i++, x += 90)
            {
PictureBoxpBox = newPictureBox();                
pBox.Height = 80;
pBox.Width = 50;
pBox.Location = newSystem.Drawing.Point(x, y);
objeto.Add(pBox);
pBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;                
Controls.Add(pBox);

var rand = newRandom();
var files = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + @"/Images", "*.gif");
pBox.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(files[rand.Next(files.Length)]);
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: There's something wrong with the formatting of the code, most blanks have been removed, making it impossible to read.

Comment: Also, it is preferred that a person asking a question provide additional information by editing the question, not by posting an answer.